# NodeList operations

Tags: javascript, nodelist

I got set of divs with integer values (always) unfortunately only with class (cannot add id because they are generated in a loop by other app i cannot mess with)

```
<div class="aaposition">3</div>
<div class="aaposition">4</div>
<div class="aaposition">5</div>
<div class="bbposition">30</div>
<div class="bbposition">30</div>
<div class="bbposition">30</div>
```

So i'm creating two nodelists (good that both lists got exact length).

```
aalist = document.getElementByClassName('aaposition');
bblist = document.getElementByClassName('bbposition');
```

What i need to do is to sum results of multiplying aaitem[i] with bbitem[i] and show it somewhere

```
sumlist = 0;
for (i = 0; i < aalist.length; i++) {
   sumlist += aalist[i] * bblist[i];
}
showdiv.innerHTML = sumlist;
```

But i don't know how to pick those values from nodelist, how can i pick the value i'm interested in?
Is it `.innerHTML`, `.value` or what?
All i found was style examples (`.style.background` ... etc.).

Also do i need to parse into integer? Do i need to convert NodeList to array?

Comment: You have made a typo in `aalist.lenght` it should be `aalist.length`

Comment: Also `getElementByClassName` is not a method. Use `document.getElementsByClassName()` I will make an answer

Comment: @SimonStaton thought it was obvious :) but of course fixed, thank you

Comment: You're multiplying DOM elements, not their inner text converted to numbers. This is probably your main problem.

Comment: Check my answer for your mistakes.

Comment: Check out [NodeList.js](https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `document.getElementsByClassName` and also fix the typo for `.length` you also need to call the nodes `.innerHTML`...

```
var result = document.getElementById('result'),
    aalist = document.getElementsByClassName('aaposition'),
    bblist = document.getElementsByClassName('bbposition'),
    sumlist = 0;

for(var i=0; i<aalist.length; i++) {
   sumlist += aalist[i].innerHTML * bblist[i].innerHTML;
}

result.innerHTML = sumlist;
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/063jmod5/)

Comment: What more can i say - it's working, thank you very much. Is there description what Node is?

Comment: You can see details on element property's here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp